# How to transpose csv data by uploaded file in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, file-upload, transpose

I'm making a desktop application using the windows form with C#, I want to make the app able to transpose the csv data (make column into rows) when user imported the file, how to write a code for it?
Here is screen shoot of my application
[user when upload a CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sihw3.png)

I already write a code inside the import button

> 

```
 private void btnImport_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtCSVFolderPath.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The Folder Path TextBox cannot be empty.", "Warning");
                    return;
                }
                else if (txtCSVFilePath.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The File Path TextBox cannot be empty.", "Warning");
                    return;
                }

                else
                {
                    ConnectCSV();
                    btnUpload.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            { }
        }
```

and the connectcsv() class

> 

```
 public DataSet ConnectCSV()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            string fileName = openFileDialogCSVFilePath.FileName;

            CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(fileName);

            ds = reader.RowEnumerator;
            dGridCSVdata.DataSource = ds;

            dGridCSVdata.DataMember = "TheData";
            return ds;
        }
```

UPDATE:

So I tried using 'StringBuilder' but doesn't makes anything happen, what's wrong with it? or is there any idea for another way?

```
public DataSet RowEnumerator
{
    get
    {
        if (null == __reader)
            throw new System.ApplicationException("I can't start reading without CSV input.");

        __rowno = 0;
        string sLine;
        string sNextLine;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("TheData");

        while (null != (sLine = __reader.ReadLine()))
        {

            while (rexRunOnLine.IsMatch(sLine) && null != (sNextLine = __reader.ReadLine()))
                sLine += "\n" + sNextLine;

            __rowno++;
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            string[] values = rexCsvSplitter.Split(sLine);
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = Csv.Unescape(values[i]);
                if (__rowno == 1)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(values[i].Trim());
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Csv.CharNotAllowes(values[i]))
                    {
                        dr[i] = values[i].Trim();
                    }

                }
            }
            if (__rowno != 1)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();// code I add for transpose the data table

        for (int u = 0; u < dt.Columns.Count; u++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(dt.Rows[i][u].ToString());

                if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    sb.Append(';');
                }
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Output.csv", sb.ToString()); 
        __reader.Close();
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you've shared your code for populating the DataSet, but not any code for transposing that DataSet. Have you tried any? Please add it to your question, along with what happened when you tried to run it.

Comment: Hi @sbridewell thank you so much for your response, I already added the code for transpose the dataset

Comment: What you're doing with the StringBuilder looks correct, Output.csv should contain the transposed version of whatever was in the DataTable, but it doesn't affect the content of the DataSet that the RowEnumerator returns. Instead, I'd suggest reading Output.csv into another DataTable and returning that DataTable in a DataSet.

Comment: Hi @sbridewell thank you for your suggestion, It worked but, why it doesn't read the first row, so from this https://imgur.com/xbuT8Cw into this https://imgur.com/zFm5rzA

Comment: So the next step is to establish whether the bug is in the code which does the transposing or in the code before it which seems to be doing validation and other manipulation of the input data which doesn't look directly relevant to the question. I'd suggest moving the transposing code into its own method (or even its own class), where you can write some unit tests for it with inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just writing some code to do the transposing, I thought it'd be more useful to walk through how I got to the answer, hence the rather lengthy answer.

There's quite a lot going on in the `RowEnumerator` property, which makes it difficult to test. Because the question is mainly asking how to transpose a `DataTable` to another `DataTable`, let's pull that transpose functionality out into its own method, or better still its own class, where it can be tested in isolation. Note that this class doesn't have any dependencies on any particular UI framework, which makes it easier to test and more reusable.

```
namespace StackOverflow74612723
{
    using System.Data;

    public static class Transposer
    {
        public static DataTable Transpose(DataTable input)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

What's the point of writing a method which just throws an exception? Answer: Now we've got the method signature, we can write some unit tests for that method, so that we can define how we expect it to behave. If you want to know more about this approach of writing unit tests before writing the code being tested, the search term you want is "test driven development".

Next, add a XUnit unit test project to your solution. You don't have to use XUnit, there are other unit test frameworks out there such as NUnit and MSTest, which can do this sort of thing. XUnit is just my personal preference. If you haven't used it before, take a look at its [documentation](https://xunit.net/#documentation), particularly the Getting Started guides.

Add a project reference to your unit test project so that it references the project containing the `Transposer` class. Add the following NuGet packages to your unit test project:

- FluentAssertions
- FluentAssertions.Analyzers
- xunit.analyzers

(the last two aren't essential but I find analyzers very useful to provide feedback on whether I'm following good coding practices). Now we can start writing a unit test for the `Transposer` class.

```
namespace StackOverflow74612723.Test
{
    using System.Data;
    using FluentAssertions;
    using Xunit;

    public class TransposerTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Unit test method for the Transpose method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">DataTable to transpose.</param>
        /// <param name="expectedOutput">
        /// Expected result of transposing the input DataTable.
        /// </param>
        [Theory]
        [MemberData(nameof(TransposeTestData))]
        public void TransposeTest(DataTable input, DataTable expectedOutput)
        {
            // nothing to arrange

            // Act
            var actualOutput = Transposer.Transpose(input);

            // Assert
            actualOutput.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

It's worth pointing out that in the Assert step, `actualOutput`, which is a `DataTable`, appears to have a `Should()` method. This is actually an extension method in the FluentAssertions package, which has many such extension methods to vastly simplify writing assertions about complex objects.

This won't build just yet because it references a property called `TransposeTestData`, which we haven't created yet. This property will provide parameterized test data to our unit test method, so that the method can be run with multiple pairs of input and expected output. For more information about parameterized tests in XUnit, see [Andrew Lock's blog](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/).

Now we can add a `TransposeTestData` property to the `TransposerTest` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a list of test cases for a Theory test for the Transpose method.
/// Each element of the list is an array of two objects, the first of
/// which is the input DataTable and the second of which is the expected
/// output of transposing the input DataTable.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<object[]> TransposeTestData =>
    new List<object[]>
    {
        // First test case
        new object[]
        {
            // input
            CreateDataTable(2)
                .Rows.Add("A1", "B1").Table
                .Rows.Add("A2", "B2").Table,

            // expected output
            CreateDataTable(2)
                .Rows.Add("A1", "A2").Table
                .Rows.Add("B1", "B2").Table,
        },

        // Second test case
        new object[]
        {
            // input
            CreateDataTable(3)
                .Rows.Add("A1", "B1", "C1").Table
                .Rows.Add("A2", "B2", "C2").Table,

            // expected output
            CreateDataTable(2)
                .Rows.Add("A1", "A2").Table
                .Rows.Add("B1", "B2").Table
                .Rows.Add("C1", "C2").Table,
        },

        // Third test case
        new object[]
        {
            // input
            CreateDataTable(4)
                .Rows.Add("A1", "B1", "C1", "D1").Table
                .Rows.Add("A2", "B2", "C2", "D2").Table
                .Rows.Add("A3", "B3", "C3", "D3").Table
                .Rows.Add("A4", "B4", "C4", "D4").Table
                .Rows.Add("A5", "B5", "C5", "D5").Table
                .Rows.Add("A6", "B6", "C6", "D6").Table
                .Rows.Add("A7", "B7", "C7", "D7").Table
                .Rows.Add("A8", "B8", "C8", "D8").Table,

            // expected output
            CreateDataTable(8)
            .Rows.Add("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8").Table
            .Rows.Add("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8").Table
            .Rows.Add("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8").Table
            .Rows.Add("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8").Table
        },
    };
```

This gives us a list of test cases, each test case being an array of objects, where the elements of the array correspond to each of the parameters of the `TransposeTest` method, so for this test, each of the object arrays needs two elements, the first being the `DataTable` we want to transpose and the second being what we expect the transposed `DataTable` to look like.

And we also need to add this little helper method, which simplifies creating the `DataTable`s in the test data.

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new DataTable with the supplied number of columns
/// and no rows.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="numberOfColumns">Number of columns.</param>
/// <returns>The DataTable.</returns>
private static DataTable CreateDataTable(int numberOfColumns)
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add();
    }

    return table;
}
```

We can now build and run the unit tests. They'll fail with a `NotImplementedException` of course, because we haven't implemented the `Transpose` method yet.

This may look like a lot of work, but it's time well spent because we now have a unit test which not only defines how we expect the `Transpose` method to behave, but will also tell us whether or not it's behaving correctly. The logic we need in the `Transpose` method is easy to get wrong, and I don't mind admitting that it took me a few attempts to get it right, in fact without the unit test I'd have probably given up.

Now we can implement the `Transpose` method in the `Transposer` class:

```
public static DataTable Transpose(DataTable input)
{
    var inputRowCount = input.Rows.Count;
    var inputColumnCount = input.Columns.Count;
    var outputRowCount = inputColumnCount;
    var outputColumnCount = inputRowCount;
    var output = new DataTable();
    for (var outputX = 0; outputX < outputColumnCount; outputX++)
    {
        output.Columns.Add();
    }

    for (var outputY = 0; outputY < outputRowCount; outputY++)
    {
        var outputRowValues = new object[outputColumnCount];
        for (var outputX = 0; outputX < outputColumnCount; outputX++)
        {
            var cellValue = input.Rows[outputX][outputY];
            outputRowValues[outputX] = cellValue;
        }

        output.Rows.Add(outputRowValues);
    }

    return output;
}
```

And because we've got the unit test, we can run it to check whether the method behaves correctly. And once we're happy that it's behaving correctly, we can call it from the `RowEnumerator` property. Rather than adding `dt` to the `DataSet` `ds`, we can transpose `dt` and add the transposed `DataTable` to `ds`, for example

```
ds.Tables.Add(Transposer.Transpose(dt));
```

I hope this answer helps you to learn about separating the concerns in your code, how to make it more easily testable, and how to test it.

Comment: hello @sbridewell thanks for your explaining about test unit. I never know before about unit test like XUnit. I already test it, but I did not understand about the running output, How do I see the input table is successfully transpose?

Comment: If you've never created unit tests before then [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/unit-test-basics?view=vs-2022) is well worth a read. It uses Microsoft's MSTest framework rather than xUnit, but most of what it says is equally applicable to any unit test framework. If you look at the second code sample in the answer, the actual unit test, I'm following the arrange, act, assert pattern, and it's the assert step which compares the actual output (transposed table) with the expected output, and if they're different then the test fails.

Comment: The parameterised test in my answer is probably a bit advanced for someone with no unit testing experience, but if you read the article (and the xUnit getting started pages) and try writing some more basic unit tests to familiarise yourself with the techniques, then the answer will start to make more sense.

Comment: can I ask a question again @sbridewell if you dont mind, How do I print the dataset that contain transposed datatable? I already tried make in into new dataset and convert it into string, but did not works, I tried same with datatable, but the output did not on transpose mode, I tried `return output.ToString()` but cannot be convert

Comment: You can do that in a very similar way to what you did with the `StringBuilder` in your question - outer loop to iterate through the rows, inner loop to iterate through the cells in the row, and this time swap the indexes round so that what's written to the `StringBuilder` isn't transposed.